# How to get a user's permissions?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm currently in the progress of migrating from the Documents List API to the Drive SDK. I had a function to check file/folder permissions of a user (per e-mail address), so I could see what rights a certain user has on a file/folder.
I think I can see why e-mail addresses are hidden from the permissions feed but is there also no 'get' function for permissions where e-mail addresses can be used as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions of the current user are in the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files#resource) as:

```
"userPermission": {
    "kind": "drive#permission",
    "etag": etag,
    "role": string,
    "additionalRoles": [
      string
    ],
    "type": string
  },
```

Comment: This'll do for now. Thanks!